# C# Monogame Minicraft get pixels Colors from png

Tags: c#, colors, sprite, pixel, monogame

I am struggling with understanding, how ColorHelper.get works in this project. [Here is C#](https://github.com/xposure/MiniCraft.NET) version from github.

*For better understanding u will need that project from github*

**About project:** The project is remake of [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2yOF4jDgNU) (in JAVA) but someone remakes this into C#. Its
a game in Monogame called Minicraft.

**Problem:** Because its open source, i wanna just play with that project and learn more. The main problem is, the color palette is limited that **I can use sprite with only 4 Colors**. That means, when I want to have colorful sprite I cant. The way how coloring works (for my opinion) is trough the ColorHelper.get function where function contains 4 ints each represent specific color. (Example [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAy5a.png))

The upper (Human) is from the game and has 4 colors which are converted by values.
The bottom sprite is my sea stuff with 8 colors. With ColorHelper.get i was able to convert only 4 colors and my sprite have to be with those 4 specific colors as that Human on the top (it cant be colorfull).

**Code:**

ColorHelper.cs

```
 public static int get(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
       
        return (get(d) << 24) + (get(c) << 16) + (get(b) << 8) + (get(a));
    }

    public static int get(int d)
    {
        if (d < 0) return 255;
        int r = d / 100 % 10;
        int g = d / 10 % 10;
        int b = d % 10;
        return r * 36 + g * 6 + b;
    }
```

Screen.cs

```
 public void render(int xp, int yp, int tile, int colors, int bits)
    {
        xp -= xOffset;
        yp -= yOffset;
        var mirrorX = (bits & BIT_MIRROR_X) > 0;
        var mirrorY = (bits & BIT_MIRROR_Y) > 0;

        var xTile = tile % 32;
        var yTile = tile / 32;
        var toffs = xTile * 8 + yTile * 8 * sheet.width;

        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
           
            int ys = y;
            if (mirrorY) ys = 7 - y;
            if (y + yp < 0 || y + yp >= h) continue;
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            {
                if (x + xp < 0 || x + xp >= w) continue;

                int xs = x;
                if (mirrorX) xs = 7 - x;
                int col = (colors >> (sheet.pixels[xs + ys * sheet.width + toffs] * 8)) & 255;
                if (col < 255)
                    pixels[(x + xp) + (y + yp) * w] = col;
            }
        }
   
    }
```

public void render(int xp, int yp, int tile, **int colors**, int bits) = **"int colors" represent

ColorHelper.get(-1,50,250,455)** (Those numbers are fictional only for example.)

**Exmaple of rendering something:**

```
//Hight of pixels 8 pixels * 2 from sprite so 16 pixels in x axis in sprite is rendered
        int h = 2;

        //Width of pixels 16 pixels * 13 in y axis in sprite is rendered
        int w = 13;

        //4 Colors sprite which i dont want ! 
        int titleColor = ColorHelper.get(0, 010, 131, 551);

        //Padding Left
        int xo = (screen.w - w * 8) / 2;

        //Padding top
        int yo = 24;

        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {
                //public void render(int xp, int yp, int tile, int colors, int bits) in Screen.cs 8x8 pixels are rendered
                screen.render(xo + x * 8, yo + y * 8, x + (y + 6) * 32, titleColor, 0);
            }
        }
```

**What I want to achieve**
When i debug a "int colors" from "public void render" i get rly weird numbers which is unreadable for me. (You can try it on your own. Just create a Console Application and paste [THIS](https://pastebin.com/xcELVQ34).

**So am I here to ask you. Is anyone who can help me remake this project, that I can get all pixels from sprite with colors as they are in png file without converting from ColorHelper.get function ?. I just want to render png as it is.**

If not, its ok,I will try to continue with struggling :D. I am actully trying to solve this about 3 days straight. I think its way to hard to remake that.

Maybe I want a lot, but my brain is not capable to understand this. Only this thing is holding me up from continuing. I hope you understand that.

**Not important info :**
If someone says that i am jumping into big projects and I should try easier stuff. I am working in Unity since 2017 and i want to have full controll of my projects and obtain some better knowladge of codding. Learnin trough the games is for my best option, coz i like games. :) For those who doesnt understand me, I am rly sorry but I am not from America, i am from Czech.

*Thank you very much.*

Comment: So I'm not very familiar with game development but I found that ColorHelper.get function a bit familiar so I'm gonna give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to comment a long block of code so I'll just put it in here. I think the .get(4 params) is trying to do this

```
//rgba ranges from 0 - 255
public static UInt32 get(int b, int g, int r, int a)
{
        UInt32 rgba = ((UInt32)a << 24) | ((UInt32)r << 16)| ((UInt32)g << 8) | 
        ((UInt32)b);
        return rgba; //this will return a 32 bit integer like 3869934080 for 
        //example
}
```

So I don't think it is taking in 4 colors at all, it's trying to take in 1 color through it's rgba input (I don't understand why it would use 555 as a range and the point of get(1 parameters) ~ maybe someone can explain it)

So if you want to display the colors you want, replace parameters r,g,b,a which in turns gives you a 32 bit unsigned int (this would probably be passed into the render function.

Resource about bit shifting [here](https://www.fayewilliams.com/2011/09/21/bitwise-rgba-values/)

Answer (score 0):

Dubre den,

To bypass the processing step and directly load the file.
To load a .png file to a Texture2D use:

Texture2D image = Texture2D.FromFile(graphicsDevice, @"C:\path\file.png");

Obviously, `image` must be used in the containing scope.